# Angularjs: process a variable before rendering

Tags: angularjs

I'm confused about how to preprocess a value before rendering it (see [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/v1W8XxeMihWR4Zced1qX?p=preview)). Basically I want to convert `rating` into a string of that number of stars (and ultimately to replucate the template many times in a page).  The way I have it, I do get `<stars rating="3"></stars>` from the first Directive but the second stage of processing is not taking place.  Any ideas?

Comment: could you post some of the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried to fix your plunkr. See here http://plnkr.co/edit/StEB85N9RZWiCmxjOX3z?p=preview

Basically i fix the attribute expression for rating and removed `{{}}` from it.

`template: '<p>Name: {{resto.rname}} Address: {{resto.address}}</p> <stars ng-attr-rating="resto.rating"></stars>'`